# Searching and replacing Pipe delimited characters in a text paragraph through regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a scenario where, in a large text, I want to identify a mail signature and remove that. The signature appears like this-

```
name | some text | some text | some text E-mail:abc@xyz.com
```

in the paragraph. Please note, the number of pipe delimiters may be three or more but at the end it has *Email*.
I need a Java code locate these portions using regex and then remove them. Any pointers would help.
Thanks in advance.

Just want to add, the signature pattern mentioned above may occur one or more times in a large text. Also the text (mentioned as *some text*) inside the pipe delimiters would change along with the name and the E-mail field.

Comment: did you try this :"\\|"

Answer (score 1):

You will find the email with:

```
[^|]+$
```

That matches everything that is not a pipe before line end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "name | some text | some text | some text E-mail:abc@xyz.com";
    String regex = ".*\\|.*\\s+";

    String email = str.replaceAll(regex, "");
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After splitting the string compare the last element of the string with the email regex, I'm sure you can find it online.

```
String[] s = yourString.split("\\|");
```